# Toolbar icon in iOS app is having a tint for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigationbar, toolbaritems

I have a xamarin forms app where i need to add a toolbar item in the navigation bar. I have a multicolored image as the tool bar icon. When i run in android devices the exact image is being shown as the toolbar icon. However in iOS it is showing as a blue image. Is there any way to get the correct multicolored icon for iOS as well?

[image]

Comment: provide screen shot and code what you have tried

Comment: @ZiyadGodil
This is the code i used
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ToolbarItem Clicked="SideMenuClicked" Icon="menu.png" Name="menu" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
And the image is attached in the question.. It shows the correct image in android. But in iOS the image color is completely blue.

Comment: Verify image first, Is same image in android and iOS resource folder?

Comment: @ZiyadGodil The images are same. It is a multicolored image. And there is a navigation bar tinting for iOS which caused the image to look default blue color in iOS. How to eliminate the navigation bar tinting for iOS in xamarin forms?

Comment: @ZiyadGodil Hello.. Any updates?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42587/toolbar-icon-showing-as-solid-color-on-ios-works-on-android

Comment: @ZiyadGodil i saw this, but i did not get a workaround as I have a dual coloured image

Comment: try with custom button and render platform specific. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11003/navigationitem-button-with-custom-image-cant-see-image

Answer (score 0):

When you create your pages using NavigationPage, Xamarin.Forms automatically creates a navigation bar on iOS. You can also modify quite a few things of the navigation bar, like this:

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, ""); // Empty text
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); // No back button
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon (this, someIcon); // Set the icon
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code App.cs**

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PointOfSaleRMSApp.LoginPage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#34C4F9"),
    BarTextColor = Color.White
};
```

Comment: Its not correct. This will change the Bar background color to the specified color and not the icon. I might have a multicolored icon but it is not possible to show as it is in this case also